# Groovy:Parse xml

Tags: xml, groovy

I want to  parse  xml   by  groovy XmlSlurper my  current xml   schema  looks  like this and  i   want   to  get    data  value  of   each  tag  (  i  mean  value of  start,startDate and endDate)  ,    have  code   like this

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(content);
        for (item in root.item){
            start=item.start;
        }
```

but  it  doesn't     work  what  should   i  change?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<serviceList>    
<ms>        
<CrossCycle>            
<details>                
<start>2017-09-07</start>                
<startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>                
<endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>                            
 </details>        
 </CrossCycle>    
 </ms>
 </serviceList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
def listOfMaps = root.ms.CrossCycle.details.collect { node -> [ 
    start: node.start.text(),
    startDate: node.startDate.text(),
    endDate: node.endDate.text()
  ]
}
```

Then `listOfMaps` is a list with a map for each `CrossCycle.details` block

ie:

```
assert listOfMaps[0].start == '2017-09-07'
```

Comment: Can  i  use  this   operation  assert listOfMaps[0].start == '2017-09-07'  for  replacing start  data   with  something  else?

Comment: no, you can do `listOfMaps[0].start = '2015-03-01'` though